Can't convert package with RemoteType 'git' to remote
I am developing an R package using renv. It depends on other packages in private Github repositories and I installed them via SSH with, e.g.:
renv::install('git@github.com:myorg/mypkg.git')

This works fine for development purposes: the installation runs without error, I can load the main package with devtools::load_all, and use the imported functions in an interactive session with no problem.
But now I'm trying to write some vignettes using devtools::build_vignettes() and it fails with the following error:
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  can't convert package mypkg with RemoteType 'git' to remote

This occurs when trying to install the package in development, i.e. devtools::install() fails in the same way.
I have tried using traceback and debug to figure this out, and while I think it's related to remotes I'm not sure what's going on here. This question is similar but the suggested solution didn't work for me (nor does it use private SSH repos).
Does anyone know what's going on here, or how I can debug it?
I'm using:

R 4.0.3
renv 1.0.7
remotes 2.5.0
devtools 2.4.5


I'd suggest writing the vignettes using a less weird setup - i.e. current R, not relying on renv.  In standard R, once a package is installed, it doesn't matter where it came from.  It seems like devtools is impeding development here, not helping it.
